# jquery parent select - more efficient way

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Is there are more efficient way than the following for selecting the third parent?

```
$(draggable).parent().parent().parent().attr('entityid')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be faster, since we're using pure DOM instead of repeatedly attaching the parent to the jQuery object.

```
jQuery.fn.getParent = function(num) {
    var last = this[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        last = last.parentNode;
    }
    return jQuery(last);
};
// usage:
$('#myElement').getParent(3);
```

Working demo: http://jsbin.com/ecoze

Comment: I like this method very much, I wanted to suggest using parentNode too, but you beat me to it.

Comment: Same can be achieved by `$("#myElement").parents(":eq(3)")`

Answer (score 2):

If you have an id, class or tagname to go by you can do `$(draggable).parents(element)`. But make sure it's unique enough that you'll get only one element, as `parents()` will retrieve multiple elements if found.

Comment: Thanks - the following suits my requirements:

$(draggable).parents('.entity').attr('entityid')