# jQuery - Getting the second level parent of an element

Tags: jquery, html, parent

I am trying to retrieve the parent of an <a> element's parent (grandparent?). I want to find that grandparent, then find a <b> tag in that element, then store that text as a variable to publish elsewhere on the page. I've been trying to use the parent() function but without success.

Here's the code I tried:

```
    $('.mixPlayCell a').click( function() {
        var title = $(this).parent().get(0).parent().get(0).text();
        alert(title);
    });
```

Comment: I don't think you understand what `.get()` does.

Comment: I most certainly do not. Everything I do in jQuery is guess and check... Could you elaborate?

Comment: Because `parent()` returns a collection with only one element, you can directly call the next function on that. The `get(0)` is implicit.

Comment: get.() is for requests.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

try:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('.thingtofind').text();
```

Comment: Look at [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108971/jquery-parent-select-more-efficent-way for faster and more elegant aproach instead using .parent().parent()....

Answer (score 72):

For selecting a second parent

```
parents(':eq(1)')
```

looks smoother than

```
parent().parent()
```

Also, you might find that

```
closest('ul')
```

fits the job better.

Answer (score 9):

[parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) returns a list, so this works:

```
$(this).parents()[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.mixPlayCell a').click(function() {
  elem = $(this).parent().parent();
  title = $("tag selector goes here",elem).html();
});
```

Something like this?

Comment: +1, .get(0) is unnecessary and returns the DOM object, which doesn't have the jQuery methods. [See here](http://static.bwerp.net/~adam/2010/04/20/parent.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is only 1 parent, no need to .get(0)

```
    var title = $(this).parent().parent().find("whateveryouwant").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('mytag').text()
```

Should work just fine.

You can use any selector in the `find` method. If you'll just need to search in the direct children of the grandparent's element, you can also use `$.children` instead of `find` which searches in all of the element's children.

Answer (score -1):

Try this for simple implementation :

```
$('.mixPlayCell a').click( function() {
    var title = $(this).parents().text();
    alert(title);
});
```

Just changed .parent() with one .parents()

this is works for every jQuery versions.